# Using COUNTIF and text based in the cell to the Left

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am looking to create a COUNTIF function based on a cell and the text based to the left of that specific cell

So in this sheet, I have the name of a person that a job has been assigned to. To the left of this I have if the job is "In Progress" or "Complete". In a table to the right, I have a list of all of the people and how many outstanding jobs they have. I want this to show the number of items they have that are "In Progress". Is there a formula to count the rows that have a specific name and then the column to the left of their name contains "In Progress"?

Thanks in advance for any help!

***My Sheet is below:***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using COUNTIFS function, the formula in cell L4 should be

```
=COUNTIFS(I:I,K4,H:H,"In Progress")
```

Drag the formula down and this should be working.

Comment: @PatrickRawlins if the solution worked for you, you should mark it as an accepted answer (by clicking the tick mark on top left of the solution where the vote section located)